# OData Multi-level query to CDS returns strange results at the 3rd level

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, microsoft-dynamics

I am querying our MS Dynamics HR Talent installation using the OData WebApi.
I am running this query:
https://nnnnnnnnnnn.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/cdm_workers?$select=cdm_fullname,cdm_primaryemailaddress&$expand=cdm_worker_employment($select=cdm_employmentnumber,cdm_ompayrollid_custom,_cdm_companyid_value;$expand=cdm_CompanyId)
using OData version 4.0.
The entities are not custom ones, but some have one or two custom fields.

When the results come back, the values for cdm_workers and for cdm_worker_employment are just what I would expect.
However the values for cdm_CompanyId are not. The values for all the fields are null, except for cdm_companyid which is what I would expect, and an extra, unexpected field named '`__DisplayName__`' which has the value I would expect to see in cdm_companycode.

Can anyone explain what is going on, and why I am seeing this behaviour?

Here is an example of the results I'm getting from this query:

```
  "value" : [ {
    "@odata.etag" : "W/\"3017162\"",
    "cdm_fullname" : "Mmmmmm Rrrrrr Tttttttt",
    "cdm_primaryemailaddress" : "mmmm.ttttttt@xyz.org",
    "cdm_workerid" : "95f1fee2-2dcb-e911-a81d-000d3a1cae2a",
    "cdm_worker_employment" : [ {
      "@odata.etag" : "W/\"3767381\"",
      "cdm_employmentnumber" : "EMPL0001029",
      "cdm_ompayrollid_custom" : "444",
      "_cdm_companyid_value" : "38d41deb-6888-e911-a81a-000d3a1cae2a",
      "_cdm_workerid_value" : "95f1fee2-2dcb-e911-a81d-000d3a1cae2a",
      "cdm_employmentid" : "bcb1f5df-2dcb-e911-a821-000d3a1ca610",
      "cdm_CompanyId" : {
        "_createdby_value" : null,
        "overriddencreatedon" : null,
        "_ownerid_value" : null,
        "timezoneruleversionnumber" : null,
        "_modifiedonbehalfby_value" : null,
        "utcconversiontimezonecode" : null,
        "_modifiedby_value" : null,
        "createdon" : null,
        "_owningbusinessunit_value" : null,
        "_owningteam_value" : null,
        "statuscode" : null,
        "cdm_name" : null,
        "versionnumber" : null,
        "_createdonbehalfby_value" : null,
        "cdm_companyid" : "38d41deb-6888-e911-a81a-000d3a1cae2a",
        "_owninguser_value" : null,
        "statecode" : null,
        "cdm_companycode" : null,
        "modifiedon" : null,
        "importsequencenumber" : null,
        "__DisplayName__" : "100",
        "IsReferencedQueryCall" : true
      }
    } ]
```

By contrast, here's the result I get for this query: https://nnnnnnnnnnn.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/cdm_companies?$filter=cdm_companyid+eq+'38d41deb-6888-e911-a81a-000d3a1cae2a'

```
  "value" : [ {
    "@odata.etag" : "W/\"3497456\"",
    "_owningbusinessunit_value" : "f1ed9fcc-496e-e911-a9b7-000d3a152d6d",
    "cdm_companyid" : "38d41deb-6888-e911-a81a-000d3a1cae2a",
    "cdm_name" : "International",
    "statecode" : 0,
    "statuscode" : 1,
    "_createdby_value" : "fe5e4d27-0b70-e911-a817-000d3a1ca508",
    "cdm_companycode" : "100",
    "_ownerid_value" : "fe5e4d27-0b70-e911-a817-000d3a1ca508",
    "_modifiedby_value" : "fe5e4d27-0b70-e911-a817-000d3a1ca508",
    "_owninguser_value" : "fe5e4d27-0b70-e911-a817-000d3a1ca508",
    "createdon" : "2019-06-06T14:39:47Z",
    "versionnumber" : 3497456,
    "modifiedon" : "2019-10-24T07:59:37Z",
    "overriddencreatedon" : null,
    "timezoneruleversionnumber" : null,
    "_modifiedonbehalfby_value" : null,
    "utcconversiontimezonecode" : null,
    "_owningteam_value" : null,
    "_createdonbehalfby_value" : null,
    "importsequencenumber" : null
  } ]
```

I was expecting to see this data in the cdm_CompanyId object of the previous results.

Comment: All are custom entities? What is the relationship between them? Show some sample data.

Comment: The Entities are not custom. One or two of the fields are. Entity cdm_workers is referenced by cdm_employments, defined by NavigationProperty cdm_worker_employment; and cdm_eployments has a reference to cdm_companies, defined by NavigationProperty cdm_CompanyId.
I have added some sample results.

Comment: @cmgharris have you figured this out? we are experiencing the same behavior

Comment: @marchello, no I don't have an answer to this yet. I've raised the issue with a company that's supposed to be helping us with our Talent development, but they haven't come back with an answer up to now. If they do, I'll post an answer.

Comment: The company through whom we are receiving support have said they are raising a ticket with Microsoft about this issue. I will post a comment/answer as and when there is anything to add.

Comment: @marchello, we have had a response to our ticket, which I have detailed in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer we have received from our support ticket is that multi-level expands are not supported.
There is a 'documentation mismatch' in the Microsoft documentation.
This page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/retrieve-entity-using-web-api#options-to-apply-to-expanded-entities says:
"You can apply certain system query options on the entities returned for a collection-valued navigation property. Use a semicolon-separated list of system query options enclosed in parentheses after the name of the collection-valued navigation property. You can use $select, $filter, $orderby, $top, and $expand.", which implies you can expand an expand, i.e. go to the third level (and further?).

However this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata#odata-services which relates to using OData with Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations, says:
"Available query options are: . . . $expand (only first-level expansion is supported)".

So the short answer is, expanding to the third level is not supported when using OData to query Talent.